# Pure JS snippet to create and delete HTML elements

Tags: javascript

I'm a server-side developer learning the ropes of pure Javascript at the moment.

One learning experiment is a web application where users post textual content, and others can comment under it via pressing a "reply" button found under each such post.

I want to do the following via vanilla JS:

1) When each reply button is pressed, create a `textarea` and `submit` button under it.

2) But if a `textarea` and `submit` button already existed under a specific reply button (when it was pressed), delete the two.

3) Remove any other existing instances of `textarea` and `submit` buttons throughout the document.

The code I've written doesn't work. Specifically, it doesn't delete the `submit` buttons as per requirement **3**, leaving behing a trail of them. Please advise.

Moreover, efficiency is also important for me, so I'd like to know the **most efficient** solution for such a scenario (if it were to scale).

---

**Here's what I'm trying:**

The `id`s of the created `textarea` and the corresponding submit button are `reply-message` and `reply-ok` respectively.

The `class` of each reply button (that produces the former elements' creation) is `rep`.

Here's a stacksnippet:

```js
var replyBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("rep");
// if replyBox already exists, hide it
for(var i = 0; i < replyBtns.length; i++) {
 replyBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Prevent submitting the form
   e.preventDefault();

   // e.target.parentNode.querySelector("#reply-message")
   var rm = this.parentNode.querySelector("#reply-message");
   if (rm != null) {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(rm);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.querySelector("#reply-ok")); 
   
   } else {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("reply-message");
     if (textarea) { 
     textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);  
     textarea.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("reply-ok"));
     }
   // Create the textarea and insert it in the form, in the next line
   var replyBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    replyBox.setAttribute('id', 'reply-message');
    replyBox.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Reply');
    // form is the parentNode of the button that was clicked on
   this.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', replyBox);
   
   var okBtn = document.createElement('button');
    okBtn.classList.add('btn', 'bcb', 'bs', 'mts');
    okBtn.setAttribute('style','border:none;height:25px;display:inline;');
    okBtn.setAttribute('id','reply-ok');
    okBtn.innerHTML = "OK";
   this.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', okBtn);
   }
 }, false);
}
```

```html
<b>POST 1:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br>
<form action="" method="POST">

   <button type="submit" class="rep" name="dec" value="1">
    reply
   </button>
   
  <button type="submit" class="" name="dec" value="2">
  delete
  </button>

   <button type="submit" class="" name="dec" value="3">
   save
   </button>
   
</form>
<hr>
<b>POST 2:</b> Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla<br>
<form action="" method="POST">

   <button type="submit" class="rep" name="dec" value="1">
    reply
   </button>
   
  <button type="submit" class="" name="dec" value="2">
  delete
  </button>

   <button type="submit" class="" name="dec" value="3">
   save
   </button>
   
</form>
<hr>
<b>POST 3:</b> Pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
<form action="" method="POST">

   <button type="submit" class="rep" name="dec" value="1">
    reply
   </button>
   
  <button type="submit" class="" name="dec" value="2">
  delete
  </button>

   <button type="submit" class="" name="dec" value="3">
   save
   </button>
   
</form>
```

Comment: The `id` of element in an HTML `document` should be unique

Comment: @guest271314: You're right, it's invalid HTML. I've reverted to classes.

Comment: There still appear to be references to duplicate `id`s at the JavaScript at `var rm = this.parentNode.querySelector("#reply-message");`

Comment: @guest271314: I'm using ids for the `textarea` and `submit` button. The way those are created, there's only one such element in the entire document at any one point. So that would be unique, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure by the JavaScript alone. Can you reproduce the current code at stacksnippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null pointer exception.

```
if (textarea) { 
    textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);  
    textarea.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("reply-ok"));
}
```

You first delete the textarea, and afterward expect to be able to acces the parent of the text area. But since the text area does not exist at this point this is impossible. You need to swap the two lines inside the if:

```
if (textarea) {  
    textarea.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("reply-ok"));
    textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea); 
}
```

Note that you also need an else there in order to prevent the new text areas to be created (if that is what you want, I'm not sure if I understood correctly)

Comment: That null pointer exception is a good catch. Beginner's mistake on my part. Thanks for the help. Also, could you guide me regarding more efficient ways to handle these kind of scenarios? Or you feel the code I've written is passable enough?

Comment: There really is no short answer to that question, but I don't think the code you have has any major flaws. Maybe split your function up into multiple functions like addButton() or something similar. I recommend you look into how to debug html (for example using the browser console to check if any exceptions where thrown)

Comment: Yep, I overlooked the debug console in this instance, will definitely stick to it next time. Regarding efficiency, my main thrust is that I shouldn't require extra iterations if something can be done more simply. Coming from a server-side background, it's something I'm very aware of. It seems a bit excessive to me that one has to parse the entire document to retrieve a single ID, e.g. `document.getElementById("reply-message");`. I suppose this is how things are done in JS, so I'll get used to it.

Comment: Well, you could create an array or some similar data structure and update it each time you create/delete an element (this would save you having to look through the document)

Answer (score 0):

Use class concept... Pass common class to your text area and button.. and on click of reply button first remove all existing text area and submit button using common class as selector.. and then simply append your newly created text area and submit button